# " Socket write error " with Java FTP connection (commons.net 3.3)

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, firewall, apache-commons

I'am working on a programm which is used to upload and download files onto a FTP server.
When I use it on my computer it works just fine. Connection to FTP, down and uploading works great!
But a friend of mine wanted to test it on his computer and noticed that the programm always caused a "socket write error".
After a little research I found out that this is about the Windows Firewall.
Obviously the windos firewall doesnt like FTP connections with java...

I tried it on a third computer with these lines in the command console:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”FTP Service” action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

after that the programm worked on the third PC.
When my friend tried it with his it wont work...

He is also using Kaspersky so I suggested he should shut down kaspersky and his windows firewall. But it still dont work. He still gets the socket write error.

In other tutorials it usually worked when people shut down their windows firewall. Do I have to configure kaspersky as well?
How would I do that?

I think it is just all about port restrictions or something like that...
When he uses fileZilla to access the ftp it works just fine.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Did you try a passive FTP connection? You can configure that somewhere in your connection settings in the java program. Maybe that avoids all the firewall problems that you are experiencing.

Comment: client.connect(HOST);
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
client.login(USER, PASS); something like that?

Comment: Yes, but you have to call the enterLocalPassiveMode() method after the login. AFAIK, otherwise it does not have an effect. From the docs about enterLocalPassiveMode(): "currently calling any connect method will reset the mode to ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE."